# How to solve this formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My math is a bit rusty so please bare with me. I am trying to solve this formula:
$$x -(x  y) = z, \quad \text{where}\quad y = 0.15 \quad\text{and}\quad z = 10 000.$$

How to get $x$?

This is what I have so far:
$$x -(0.15x) = 10 000$$ 
$$-(0.15x) = 10000 - x$$
$$-x  = (10000 - x)/0.15$$

Now I am stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x-xy=z$

$x(1-y)=z$

$x=\cfrac{z}{1-y}$ since $y \not= 1$